# Wordpress site showing special charactors in site

Tags: php, wordpress, special-characters

My customer has a WordPress site and last week we have migrated it to a cPanel server after that the site showing special characters like `!` and `?` in the website. Can somebody let me know how to remove this?

> Server: Centos 6
>
> cPanel: WHM 56.0
>
> PHP   : 5.6.23
>
> MySQL : 5.6

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate the issue

Comment: Could you please explain above issue with screen shot ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to support UTF-8 completely in a web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/how-to-support-utf-8-completely-in-a-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

It's UTF8 Encoding problem, sometimes it happens when you migrate wordpress site from one host to another, you should select correct character set while exporting database backup.

Open and edit your WordPress wp-config.php file. Then find the following two lines and if it is not like that then you should change them as shown below.

define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', ');

If this doesn't work try googling "special character problem wordpress"

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.6 changes the default value of default_charset to UTF-8. Change that value to `ISO-8859-1` in your `php.ini` file and restart apache. See if that fix the issue.

**Or** convert the encoding of php textfiles to utf8 and don't change defaults.